# Installing Braintree Package but error message appears "Package Naxam.BrainTreeCore.iOS 4.8.2 is not compatible with netstandard2.1"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, nuget, braintree

I'm trying to install a package called "Naxam.BraintreeCard.IOS" so I can process payments through Paypal's Braintree.

Upon installing, an error appears in the package console:

> Package Naxam.BrainTreeCore.iOS 4.8.2 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Naxam.BrainTreeCore.iOS 4.8.2 supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)

How do I get around this?

Comment: Thanks @MickyD how did you do that?

Comment: Welcome recent member.  I have edited your question to format the error message using the `>` prefix rather than ``` as the latter is for matting code or program output (excluding errors).   `>` is great for _quotes_. :)

Comment: Haha you beat me to it.  I was in the middle of writing the comment when you did :)

Comment: thanks again, i'll remember to use the prefix next time :)

Comment: Not a problem good sir :)

Comment: This plugin is only for Xamarin.iOS project. So install it only to .iOS project instead of xamarin.forms/xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT that makes sense.

Comment: @Khoa I just added an answer and  can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is only for Xamarin.iOS project. So install it only to .iOS project instead of xamarin.forms/xamarin.Android project.